# python csv field replace if it has specific value

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python but have experience  with C/sh/java..
My first homework is csv field replacement, if field has specific value

My csv file has 24 columns and has ~ as field seperator.
I want to change field 24th with T if it's True
My code is like that

```
import csv
with open ('MyCustomerList.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8' ) as fi:
    reader = csv.reader (fi, delimiter = '~')
    for row in reader:
        if row[23] == 'True':
            print (row[23])
```

But it gives an error like that

```
C:\>c:\Python34\python.exe pyt1.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "pyt1.py", line 5, in <module>
        if row[23] == 'True':
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I could not figured out the issue
what is the error ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: IndexError: list index out of range Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479465/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-error)

Comment: Looks like at least one of the rows in the csv file doesn't have 24 items in it. You could wrap the statements where the exception get raised in a `try/except` and handle the issue as necessary (abort, ignore, substitute, etc) in the `except` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 'list index out of range' says that you tried to get element after the array ends. I assume that your file really has 24 values, so at first try printing all of them out with index:

```
i = 0
for row in reader:
    print (i + ' ' + row)
    i += 1
```

and check if you really get 23rd field (indexing from 0 :).

Comment: Thanks, csv was corrupted